# Simple proportion error in using the sum() function in Tidyverse in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm not really sure what can be wrong with the function that I wrote. It uses the `gss_cat` data frame that comes in R. All I was trying to do was calculate a simple proportion, but for some reason the `sum()` function is reading each individual cell and using that as the output. Here is the code:

`by_age = gss_cat %>% filter(!is.na(age)) %>% group_by(age, marital) %>% count() %>% mutate(prop = n/sum(n))`

What I expect to occur is that for each row I get a proportion, so for example the proportion for row 1 should be:  $\frac{89}{sum(n)}$.

Instead what is happening is that I am getting 1, where `sum(n) = 89` as well, but I expect sum(n) to sum up all of the quantities in all 351 rows and use that as its output.

I've done these sorts of calculations before and haven't had a problem. I don't think there is an issue with the variable name being "n" either.

Comment: can you please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is still grouped when you are using `mutate` in the last line.

One way is to `ungroup` after `count`

```
library(dplyr)

gss_cat %>% 
  filter(!is.na(age)) %>% 
  group_by(age, marital) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(prop = n/sum(n))
```

Or a simpler method is to not group at all and use variables in `count`.

```
gss_cat %>% 
  filter(!is.na(age)) %>% 
  count(age, marital) %>% 
  mutate(prop = n/sum(n))


# A tibble: 351 x 4
#     age marital           n      prop
#   <int> <fct>         <int>     <dbl>
# 1    18 Never married    89 0.00416  
# 2    18 Married           2 0.0000934
# 3    19 Never married   234 0.0109   
# 4    19 Divorced          3 0.000140 
# 5    19 Widowed           1 0.0000467
# 6    19 Married          11 0.000514 
# 7    20 Never married   227 0.0106   
# 8    20 Separated         1 0.0000467
# 9    20 Divorced          2 0.0000934
#10    20 Married          21 0.000981 
# … with 341 more rows
```

Comment: To make sure I understand the mistake I made, when my data was still grouped the behaviour that was happening was that ```sum(n)``` was only taking the values from that specific group, for example in row 1 it was only summing up the counted elements of row 1 only.

Comment: Yes, since `count` keeps only 1 row per group and you can see that your data is still grouped after `count` (`gss_cat %>% 
    filter(!is.na(age)) %>% 
    group_by(age, marital) %>% 
    count()`) hence each row becomes one group and `sum` of only 1 row is taken.